# Better way to display table data in react

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am working on my personal project where i came across one functionality where I might need to:

- Display Json data into table form.
- User can select specific date range and table should display data on selected date.

I have the following design to consider:
[image]

Based on Research I found:
1) I would use react-daterange to place top left date range picker
2) To display table I found react-bootstrap-table2 would be a reasonable solution to display Json data.

Here I have some solution in my mind, but I am asking if someone have better suggestion for this table view. 
The only tricky part i Found is to update table column header based on date range selection.

I would like to Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: depending on your needs, it may be simpler for you to just make a <table> instead of using the `react-bootstrap-table2` library.

Comment: I wanted to make table cell editable and react-bootstrap-table2 provides great way to make cell editable. That is the only reason to use react-bootstrap-table2.

Comment: https://material-ui.com